# Django Rename dictionary value

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
context['income'] = Income.objects.filter(assigned_to__username=self.request.user). \
                                   filter(status=Income.STATUS_PENDING). \
                                   annotate(month=ExtractMonth('created')).values('month'). \
                                   annotate(value=Coalesce(Sum('value'), 0)).values('month', 'value')
```

which will return everytime something like this:

```
<QuerySet [{'month': 9, 'value': Decimal('12.50')}]>
```

Instead the month number i wish to display the month in words:
1 - January, 2 - February ... 9 - September etc. How can i do this?

I want to use this in a chart where monthly there will be displayed the total value in a month.

template.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Morris.Bar({
            element: 'Income',
            data: [
                {% for item in income %}
                    { Month: '{{ item.month }}', Income: '{{ item.value }}' },
                {% endfor %}
            ],
            xkey: 'Month',
            ykeys: ['Income'],
            labels: ['Euro'],
            resize: true,
            lineColors: ['#33414E', '#95B75D']
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: OK, so what is your question?

Comment: How can i change the dict value 1, 2, 3 into January, February, March and so on.. ?

Comment: can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple array lookup in your JS is the easiest way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', ...];
    Morris.Bar({
        element: 'Income',
        data: [
            {% for item in income %}
                { Month: monthNames[{{ item.month }} - 1], Income: '{{ item.value }}' },
            {% endfor %}
        ],
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use [templatefilter-date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date):

```
{ Month: '{{ item.month|date:"F" }}', Income: '{{ item.value }}' },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Income.objects.filter(assigned_to__username=self.request.user).\
    extra(select={'month': "MONTHNAME(created)"}).\
    values('month')
```

Comment: Want to provide some kind of explaination?